# is there a way to check who has opened the macro?

Tags: excel, vba

i have an XLAM macro that runs as an add in. can i write a script in any language to identify the user (IP address or name of computer) who is currently using the macro??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not?
Use the `Application.UserName` property.

If that's not enough, then use the [GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724295(VS.85).aspx) function:

```
Private Declare Function GetComputerName Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, ByRef nSize As Long) As Long
```